# How to use json naming strategy in @Serdeable annotation

Tags: java, kotlin, micronaut

I have upgraded my [Micronaut](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-serialization/latest/guide/) application to `4.1.6` and from then i'm facing serialization & deserialization strategy issue. With the older version of micronuat i'm able to get the `snake-case` strategy using `application.yml` property

```
jackson:
   property-naming-strategy: SNAKE_CASE
```

But with the upgrades this property is not working and i'm getting response in camel case like below

```
 {
    "id": "84984710",
   "partId": 1111144,
   "testChangeEvents": {}
 }
```

I'm using [@Serdeable](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-serialization/latest/guide/) on `data` classes for serialization or deserialization as per document

> Declare the @Serdeable annotation at the type level in your source code to allow the type to be serialized or deserialized.

But when i'm trying to specify `naming strategy` using `naming` attribute i'm facing issues

```
  @Serdeable(naming = PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE.javaClass.kotlin)
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
  data class TestTask(

     val id: Long,
     val partId: Long,
     val TestChangeEvents testChangeEvents,
  )
```

**Error**

```
 An annotation argument must be a class literal (T::class)

 public val <T : Any> T.javaClass: Class<T>

 Returns the runtime Java class of this object.
 kotlin.jvm   JvmClassMappingKt.class 
 Gradle: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22 (kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar)
```

Answer (score 0):

The current [source of Micronaut Serialization](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-serialization/) tells me that `@Serdeable` takes the parameter `naming` which is of type `Class<? extends PropertyNamingStrategy>` (as seen [here](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-serialization/blob/master/serde-api/src/main/java/io/micronaut/serde/annotation/Serdeable.java#L58)). This is a `java.lang.Class` and not a `kotlin.reflect.KClass`, which means that the bug in your code is that it should just be `PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE.javaClass`, without the `.kotlin` afterwards (btw, if you *do* want the `KClass`, use `::class` instead of `.javaClass.kotlin`).

Alternatively, you can use [`io.micronaut.serde.config.naming.SnakeCaseStrategy`](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-serialization/blob/master/serde-api/src/main/java/io/micronaut/serde/config/naming/SnakeCaseStrategy.java) directly by doing `naming = SnakeCaseStrategy::class.javaClass`.

tl;dr you can choose one of these options:

```kotlin
@Serdeable(naming = PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE.javaClass)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
data class TestTask(
   val id: Long,
   val partId: Long,
   val TestChangeEvents testChangeEvents,
)
```

or

```kotlin
@Serdeable(naming = SnakeCaseStrategy::class.javaClass)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
data class TestTask(
   val id: Long,
   val partId: Long,
   val TestChangeEvents testChangeEvents,
)
```